# Create word document from SQL Server Management Studio - 1 row per page (email templates for client to view)

Tags: sql-server, formatting, document, documentation-generation

Hey there I have a simple EmailTemplate table with three columns:

TemplateName
EmailSubject
EmailContent

I have a client that wants to review all the templates and I'd like to put them into a word document, 1 per page, in the order they are above e.g.

-------------- page 1 --------------

[[TemplateName]]

[[EmailSubject]]

[[EmailContent]]
...
...
...
[[EmailContent]]

-------------- page 2 --------------

[[TemplateName]]

[[EmailSubject]]

[[EmailContent]]
...
...
...
[[EmailContent]]

Does anyone one know of an easy way to do this from SQL Server Management Studio?

Cheers
Rob

Comment: Isn't SSMS just for querying for data and running traces and such or did they add export options of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Word has a mail merge function that can be used with csv data, I'd recommend that over any attempt to build the entire thing in sql.

Comment: I started down this path and realised that I can't just jump on, use the mail merge wizard and off I go as the Mail Merge wizard is geared for address fields, so I'd then have to go down the path of setting up custom fields etc which is more effort than I want to invest in this process/client.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more searching, lot's of code solutions but nothing out-of-the-box in SSMS so I did some more fiddling and here's what I did to achieve this:

1. Set the query output to text
2. Set the Query -> Query Options -> Text to: no headings and Delimeter | (so it's easy to remove)
3. Added formatting to the query with Tabs CHAR(9) and Line Breaks CHAR(10) as follows:

   SELECT 
   'Template Name:' + CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + Name + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10),
   'Email Subject:' + CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + TemplateSubject + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10),
   'Contents:' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10),
   TemplateContent + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) +  CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + '------------------------------------' FROM dbo.EmailTemplate

I just copy/paste this contents into Word and then went through and converted the dashed line "----" to page breaks and sent it off to the client to review.